# Qmail in Plesk is suddenly unable to send any message

Tags: centos, email, domainkeys

I have a weird problem on Plesk 8.6 (CentOS 5.7).

After a server restart, no mail gets delivered thru qmail. Neither to the local mailboxes nor to external addresses. All mail gets accepted, and no error message gets thrown, but the mails disappear. They're not even in the queue. The queue is empty.

In the maillog (/usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog) I get errormessages like this:

```
all addreses are uncheckable - need to skip scanning (by deny mode)
```

and later:

```
Unable to check directory entry dd51-domainkeys: Invalid argument
```

DNS works (for example `dig MX gmail.com` returns the appropriate records).
I can also telnet to port 25 on external servers.

An example log showing what happens from the mail arriving until giving up can be found here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4392893/qmail-issue-log.txt

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After two months of behaving this way, there was a server restart at the farm and all of a sudden it started to work again. I don't know what was the reason behind, as I also restarted several times when I tried to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below files has anything entries related to the problem domains: artxxxxx.com, hsx.artxxxxx.com

`/var/qmail/control/locals`

`/var/qmail/control/virtualdomains`